# MERN App with JWT authentication storing token on cookie always returns 401 on requests

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt, mern

I am doing a react app and I had the authentication storing the JWT on localstorage, then I read about xss attacks and changed my mind to use cookies to store the JWT token, I have refactor my code to achieve this but after logging I try to do a request but always get unauthorized, I logged the headers sent by the client and the token is being sent, the server have the headers to allow the credentials i.e

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
```

but still get 401 error. the code I have is this:

also the React client is running on: http://192.168.1.18:3000
and express server on : http://192.168.1.18:3005

**Client side**

this is the request I am attempting to do:

```
.
.
.
await axios.get(http://192.168.1.18:3005'+/admin/match',{
 withCredentials: true
})
.
.
.
```

**Server Side:**

the login logic:

```
router.post('/login', cors.corsWithOptions, passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res,next) => {

  var token = authenticate.getToken({
    _id: req.user._id,
  firstname: req.user.firstname,
  lastname: req.user.lastname});
  
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.cookie('token', token, {
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false
  });
  res.send({success:true});

});
```

here  `cors.corsWithOptions` is a custom middleware where i configure CORS

**CORS middleware:**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const whitelist = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://192.168.1.18:3000',    
];
var corsOptionsDelegate = (req, callback) => {
    var corsOptions;
    if(whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
        corsOptions = { origin: true }; // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response
    } else {
        corsOptions = { origin: false }; // disable CORS for this request
    }
    callback(null, corsOptions); // callback expects two parameters: error and options
}

exports.cors = cors({

    credentials: true,
}
);
exports.corsWithOptions = cors(corsOptionsDelegate);
```

and the admin/match route that the client is doing the request but returning 401:

```
adminRouter.route('/match')
.options(cors.corsWithOptions, (req, res) => { res.sendStatus(200); })

// GET Endpoint
// This endpoint compare the car information of all the records of interesForms model with the
// records of cars model that has status almacen, and return the cars that match with the
// interesForm information and also the interesForm information that match with the cars

// This endpoint also compare the car information of all the records of interesForms model with the
// records of ofertasForms that match with the interesForm information
// and return the car with the contact information of the ofertaForm and also the interesForm information 
// that match with the cars

.get(cors.cors, authenticate.verifyUser, authenticate.verifyAdmin, (req,res,next) => {
  .
  .
  .
  // here is the logic of the route.
  .
  .
  .
})
```

and the `authenticate.verifyUser, authenticate.verifyAdmin` are two middlewares that verify if the request is done by a user and an admin:

**authenticate middleware**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('./models/user');
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
var ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var config = require('./config');

exports.local = passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

exports.getToken = function(user) {
    return jwt.sign(user, config.secretKey,
        {expiresIn: 3600});
};

var opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = config.secretKey;

exports.jwtPassport = passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts,
    (jwt_payload, done) => {
        console.log("JWT payload: ", jwt_payload);
        User.findOne({_id: jwt_payload._id}, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            else if (user) {
                return done(null, user);
            }
            else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }));

exports.verifyUser = passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false});

exports.verifyAdmin = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.user.admin) {
        next();
    } else {
        var err = new Error('Unauthorized, you are not allowed to access this page :(');
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
    }
}
```

why I am not able to authenticate regarding the token is being sent on the request headers of the client? also I saw that cookies can just be shared on the same url so I defined a proxy on the package.json like this:

```
{
  "proxy" : "http://192.168.1.18:3005"
}
```

so the request is done like this `await axios.get(/admin/match'....` but still can't be authorized.

here is a image of the request headers.

How can I fix this? Am I doing something bad with the proxy or CORS or Headers?

[image: request headers]

Comment: Are you able to see the token in export.jwtPassport where you have the console log for jwt_payload?

Comment: thanks for taking the time to read the question and ask, I am not able to see it, but when using localstorage I can see it, I think I cant see this because the request is not completed and always return 401 but I am not sure

Comment: Do you know which part of your code returns 401? Otherwise first try printing the token with removing all middleware so that we can isolate the problem that is whether the token is being sent or not

Comment: I did that, removed all middlewares and the token is printed in the `req.cookies`, and the 401 is returned on the  `adminRouter.route('/match')` route when the React client do the request

Comment: I redo that, started to erase middlewares one per one and the one with the problem is authenticate.verifyUser,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

passport.authenticate('jwt') expects authorization header or other similar fields but not cookie.

http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/

There is a different mechanism to use cookies as authorization with passport

http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt-cookiecombo/

Edit: passport-jwt-cookiecombo is depreciated. Token can be manually extracted and used in passport.authenticate

Reference: https://alphonso-javier.medium.com/building-httponly-cookie-jwt-authentication-with-passport-js-27ec519b99c1

Comment: thanks you a lot, din't thought about that. happy new year

Comment: just saw and seems that this cookiecombo is deprecated

Comment: You can extract token from cookie manually like this https://alphonso-javier.medium.com/building-httponly-cookie-jwt-authentication-with-passport-js-27ec519b99c1